# minus 2 sub query in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a challenge in how to minus to subquery in one query. I dont know if this is possible or if there is a way around it. Ill appreciate anyhelp i can get pls. Thanks.

```
 $query = SELECT name, email, (SELECT SUM(tx_amount) FROM #__tx WHERE (tx_from = id
 AND tx_from_code = code AND tx_type1 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved') OR 
(tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND tx_type2 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved')) as Wallet_Balance, 
(SELECT SUM(tx_amount) FROM #__tx WHERE (tx_from = id AND tx_from_code = code AND 
tx_type1 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved') OR (tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND 
tx_type2 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved')) as Wallet_Balancee, (Wallet_Balance-Wallet_Balancee) as Total FROM users WHERE id = '$id');
```

I keep getting the error Unknown column 'Wallet_Balance' in 'field list'
Kindly help with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query.  The problem is simple.  You cannot use column aliases in the same `select` clause.

```
SELECT name, email,
       (SELECT SUM(tx_amount)
        FROM #__tx
        WHERE (tx_from = id AND tx_from_code = code AND
               tx_type1 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
              ) OR 
              (tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND
               tx_type2 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
              )
       ) as Wallet_Balance, 
       (SELECT SUM(tx_amount)
        FROM #__tx
        WHERE (tx_from = id AND tx_from_code = code AND 
               tx_type1 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
              ) OR
              (tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND 
               tx_type2 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
              )
       )  as Wallet_Balancee,
      (Wallet_Balance-Wallet_Balancee) as Total
FROM users
WHERE id = '$id';
```

You have several options.  The simplest is probably to just to use a subquery:

```
SELECT name, email, Wallet_Balance, Wallet_Balancee,
       (Wallet_Balance-Wallet_Balancee) as Total
FROM (SELECT name, email,
             (SELECT SUM(tx_amount)
              FROM #__tx
              WHERE (tx_from = id AND tx_from_code = code AND
                     tx_type1 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
                    ) OR 
                    (tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND
                     tx_type2 = 'Credit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
                    )
             ) as Wallet_Balance, 
             (SELECT SUM(tx_amount)
              FROM #__tx
              WHERE (tx_from = id AND tx_from_code = code AND 
                     tx_type1 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
                    ) OR
                    (tx_to = id AND tx_to_code = code AND 
                     tx_type2 = 'Debit' AND tx_status = 'Approved'
                    )
             )  as Wallet_Balancee
      FROM users
      WHERE id = '$id';
     ) w;
```

You are selecting data for only one user, so the overhead of creating a derived table is exceedingly small.